# How to fix table with corrupt rows

Tags: sql-server, corruption, dbcc

I was inserting records into a table, when I suddenly got disconnected from the DB server

When I tried doing a row count on the table, I got a fatal error 824

I tried `DBCC CHECKTABLE` and it indicated that the table had consistency errors, and recommended `repair_allow_data_loss`

The table has 49021 rows, and I can still select the 49013 rows and accessing the rows beyond that yields to the fatal error 824

The records I was trying to insert into the table are not very important, and are just test data. I was wondering if it would be safe to perform repair_allow_data_loss in that matter?

Or is there any workaround in removing the corrupted rows from the table?

We have a backup table, and I was wondering if doing a truncate on the table and inserting the data from the backup table will work?

Comment: Restoring from a backup to a (new!) machine, if you have a backup, is always your best bet. `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`, as the name implies, can cause data loss, and is in fact not shy about doing so as long as it ends up with a consistent database. Also, as long as you don't know the actual cause of the data loss, you should assume any action you undertake on the server can cause *more* data loss, even if designed to fix things, so tread lightly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use a DBCC CHECK ... REPAIR of any kind, before having evaluate the disk "surface". In 99 % the storage is clearly the point that cause those trouble and attempting to repair a faulty disk is the best way to increase corruptions.

Try to migrate the files to another disk and after analyse what is corrupted.

If it is only a user index with idex id > 2 then drop the index an recreate it.

If it is a user table you can recover your table from BACKUPs in doing a RESTORE ... PAGE. If the affected file(groups) haven't been read-only since that backup was performed, then you also need an unbroken chain of log backups, up to current point-in-time.

If you have alwaysOn active this could be auto repaired.

If none of those technichs repairs your corruptions, then the only solution is to apply a DBCC with the REPAIR ALLOW DATA LOSS option. With this last option, and due to integrity and check constraints it is highly recommended to follow the process with a DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS to identify parts of data loss (as an exemple an order without the customer);

If you can read the french, here is a paper I wrote about all this process :
Correction des bases SQL Server corrompues
https://blog.developpez.com/sqlpro/p12902/ms-sql-server/correction-des-bases-sql-server-corrompues